# rowMeans() and mean() return different values?

Tags: r

I'm not sure why these two methods for getting the average return different values. The second bit of code is convoluded, I know. This question isn't about making the code better but finding out what the difference is, why they're returning different results.

Thanks!

```
data(iris)
sepal_avg <- select(iris, starts_with("Sepal")) %>% rowMeans()

iris$id <- c(1:length(iris$Sepal.Length))
sepal_avg2 <- iris %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(sepal_average = mean(Sepal.Length:Sepal.Width))

sepal_avg == sepal_avg2$sepal_average
```

Comment: I think you were confused because you can select columns using `:` in `vars` argument of `summarise_at`/`mutate_at` etc but that is not the case with `mean`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mean(c(x,y))` gives the mean of `x` and `y`, but you wrote `mean(x:y)`, with the `:` operator, which is the sequence of numbers from `x` to `y` (try ?`:`at the console for more info). That's equivalent for integers, but note that these are different:

```
> mean(2.1:12.6)
[1] 7.1
> mean(c(2.1, 12.6))
[1] 7.35
```

because:

```
> 2.1:12.6
 [1]  2.1  3.1  4.1  5.1  6.1  7.1  8.1  9.1 10.1 11.1 12.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using columns incorrectly in the second approach.

The following code is doing not what you expects:

```
summarise(sepal_average = mean(Sepal.Length:Sepal.Width))
```

Argument of the `mean` is `Sepal.Length:Sepal.Width` and when it executes, it does not take this two columns.

Instead, it substitutes the column names with column values and generates regular sequence with the help of `:`:

```
> 5.1:3.5
[1] 5.1 4.1
> mean(5.1:3.5)
[1] 4.6
```

The mean result is exactly what you got for `id = 1`.

Instead, you should pass values:

```
sepal_average = mean(c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))
```